# importing wordpress header into vbulletin

Tags: html, wordpress, vbulletin

Ive made a plugin to import the header from my wp site to the vb forums header so that the user has one common header to the site. The error on calling the plugin in my header template in vb forums is

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function language_attributes() in /home/alhussai/public_html/wp-content/themes/Karma/header.php on line 2
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Can we see your code that threw the error?

Comment: ob_start();
  require_once('/home/alhussai/public_html/wp-content/themes/Karma/header.php');
  $php_include = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
vB_Template::preRegister('Test',array('php_include' => $php_include));

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but some WordPress header templates have a dynamic language attribute. It should look something like this in your header.php file, pretty close to the top of the page:

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
```

You could change it to this:

```
<html lang="en">
```